# The usage of chip away at

Tags: phrases, sentence

I just came across an article that used the phrase "chip away at."

But my question is that I actually don't understand that sentence

[image]

As I'm not familiar with this phrase and not good at grammar either, I'm not sure if the author means: Davidai's made the compromise that he would satisfy the wanderlust

or
he would reduce the frequency of travelling?

I'm lost, can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you chip away at something such as an idea, a feeling, or a system, you gradually make it weaker or less likely to succeed by repeated efforts. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/chip-away-at

Comment: @user121863 thanks, but does it suggest Davidai's keen on travelling, and he decided to only takes one trip a year right now or what?